# How to add something to var many times?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with 6 checkboxes, var result and 6 if.
When a user checks a checkbox, text is added to a variable.

But when I call `alert()`, it shows me only the last checkbox.

How to add text multiple times to one var?

```
if (otvetp == "1") {
    var result += '<img src="rez/1.png">';
}

document.getElementById('vse').innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Please post your code as well before your question get closed.

Comment: okay it's done            .

Comment: Because you redeclare your var result in each condition, declare var result before your if else if and jsute use result +=

Comment: what text is added to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = '';

if (otvetp == "1") {
    result += '<img src="rez/1.png">';
}

document.getElementById('vse').innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function myfunction()
        {   
    var result='';
        var tags=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

 for (var i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
{
if(tags[i].checked)
result+=tags[i].value;
}
//alert(result);
document.getElementById('vse').innerHTML = result;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 1" 

onclick="myfunction()">checkbox 1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 2" 

onclick="myfunction()">checkbox 2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 3" 

onclick="myfunction()">checkbox 3</input>
    <input type="checkbox" value="checkbox 4" 

onclick="myfunction()">checkbox 4</input>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

What that might be happening for you is that the variable `result` is being created every time for you as you've written

```
var result += '<img src="rez/1.png">';
```

So everytime the checkbox is checked new variable is being created and to that variable the value is being attached. So you get the last checkbox.